# No output when I try to check if each letter of a word is in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a code where the program should read a file and check if the letters from the word aardvark are in it. the letters can be in any lower or upper case. Every time I run my code, nothing gets printed. Instead, it should print:

```
Aardvark on line *line number*
```

I have already tried to use a list to check if each letter in aardvark is in the file. I have also tried checking it as a string.
Here are a few pieces of code I've tried to use:

1) `if 'aardvark' in line:
      print(line)`

2) `if list(word)  in anylist:
    print('Word in list')`

3)  `if any(word) in anylist:
        print('Word in list')`

Every time I try to turn the Aardvark into a list (like on code 2), I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "program.py", line 9, in <module>
    if a.split() in word:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list`
```

This is my code so far:

```
    a = 'aardvark'

with open('input.txt') as fp:
  fp = fp.read()
  for i, line in enumerate(fp):
    i+=1
    if 'aardvark' in line:
      print(line)
```

Comment: Could you show a sample of your `input.txt` file?

Comment: Your code only has 8 lines, and the error is in line 9, which you do not show. The error seems to have nothing to do with the code you show.

Comment: What do you mean by "check if the letters from the word aardvark are in" ? Should it detect lines containing those letters even if out of order and / or not consecutive ? Or just "the word aardvark in any combination of upper/lower case" ? Also what if it's actually part of bigger word ie should " fooaardvark " be a positive ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have use nay extra variables etc, always try to make code as pythonic as possible when you are using python.

Here is simple 4-line solution for you:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if 'aardvark' in line.lower():
            print('Aardvark on line:', num)
```

Comment: Hint: `enumerate()` accepts an optional `start` argument so you can use `enumerate(f, 1)` and avoid the `num+1` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

FIX

```py
a = 'aardvark'

with open('input.txt') as fp:
  lines = fp.readlines()
  c = 1
  for line in lines:
    if 'aardvark' in line.lower():
      print(a, "in line",c)
    c+=1
```

What I am doing is reading the entire file as lines and storing it in a list. Then iterating over the list and checking if `aardvark` exists in the line. Note that I converted the line to lower case for matching and I am using a counter variable `c` to keep a count of the line.
Hope this helps. Cheers :)

Comment: You should avoid reading a whole file in memory unless you have compelling reasons to do so - even on todays harware, memory is not a free resource. Better to iterate over the file. Also you may be interested in the `enumerate(iterable)` builtin function.

Comment: yes I agree with you. By the qestion I assumed questioner is a beginner. So I kept the approach as simple as possible

Comment: That's a nice intent, but 1/ it's important to teach proper ways when the OP is a beginner (else how will they learn ?),  2/ your answer will be read by thousands other beginners si point 1 is even more important when you think about it,  and finally  3/ in this case the idiomatic solution is actually simpler than your own ;-)

Comment: Yeah I guess you are right. Can't debate on these points. Thanks for the insight. I'll delete my answer